# How do I randomly open a file with a specific tag in AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

I wrote this simple AppleScript that opens a random file in a specific directory.

```
tell application "Finder"
    open some file of folder "Macintosh HD:Users:userName:brah:brah:pdffiles"
end tell
```

I am trying to find a way to open a random file **with a specific Finder tag**. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean *"with a specific tag"*? Which specific tag, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
use AppleScript version "2.3.1"
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set theFolder to path to pictures folder
tell application "Finder" to set theItems to (every file of theFolder) as alias list

set tagList to {"Κόκκινη"} -- specific tag (as list), may be multiple

-- get all files with specified tagList
set filesList to {}
repeat with thisItem in theItems
    set itsTags to (its returnTagsFor:(POSIX path of thisItem))
    if itsTags contains tagList then set end of filesList to (contents of thisItem)
end repeat

-- return random item (file) from filesList
if not (filesList is {}) then return contents of some item of filesList

on returnTagsFor:posixPath -- get the tags
    set aURL to current application's |NSURL|'s fileURLWithPath:posixPath -- make URL
    set {theResult, theTags} to aURL's getResourceValue:(reference) forKey:(current application's NSURLTagNamesKey) |error|:(missing value)
    if theTags = missing value then return {} -- because when there are none, it returns missing value
    return theTags as list
end returnTagsFor:
```